# How can I change the tkinter code to draw randomly every time press button?

Tags: python, tkinter, random

I want to write a code so that every time I press the button, a different flag is drawn. But now, when a flag is drawn by pressing a random button, even if I press it again, only the national flag of that country is drawn. That part is def button27_pressed():. And 랜덤 means random. How can I change the code to draw randomly flag every time I press the button?

```
from tkinter import *
from turtle import*
from Random import FlagPrint
import random

from 중국 import China
from 체코 import Czeh
from 태국 import Thailand
from 튀니지 import Tunisia
from 프랑스 import France
from 헝가리 import Hungary

window=Tk()
window.title("거북이를 이용한 국기 그리기")
window.geometry("540x320")



def button27_pressed():

    Country=['그리스','대한민국','덴마크','독일','라트비아','룩셈부르크',
            '리투아니아','말리','미국','바하마','방글라데시','벨기에',
            '스위스','아이슬란드','아일랜드','영국','오스트리아','이탈리아',
            '인도','일본','중국','체코','태국','튀니지','프랑스','헝가리']

    Flag=random.choice(Country)

    FlagPrint()
```

This is FlagPrint code.

```
def FlagPrint():
    if(Flag=='그리스'):
       Greece()

    elif(Flag=='대한민국'):
         Korea()

    elif(Flag=='덴마크'):
         Denmark()

    elif(Flag=='독일'):
         Germany()
```

Ths is exampe of France.

```
from turtle import *

def France():

    reset()

    colormode(255)
    speed(7)
    setup(900, 900)

    penup()
    goto(-375, 250)
    pendown()

    # Blue Rectangle
    color(0,85,164)
    begin_fill()
    forward(250)
    right(90)
    forward(500)
    right(90)
    forward(250)
    end_fill()

    right(180)
    penup()
    forward(500)
    pendown()

    # Red Rectangle
    color(239,65,53)
    begin_fill()
    forward(250)
    left(90)
    forward(500)
    left(90)
    forward(250)
    end_fill()

    hideturtle()
```

Comment: Here is that part 'def button27_pressed():'. This part is about to random flag.

Comment: `FlagPrint(Flag)` instead of `FlagPrint()` ?

Comment: It doesn't work.

Comment: Can we see an example of how France, Hungary etc. is defined?

Comment: Should the `Flag` in `Flag=random.choice(Country)` be `Random.Flag` instead (need `import Random`)?

Comment: On an unrelated note, I would recommend using a dictionary rather than this long `if ... elif .. elif`, e.g. `flags = {'그리스': Greece, '대한민국': Korea ...}`, then define `FlagPrint` as `flags[Flag]()` (and maybe add some error handling)

Comment: You've posted way too much code. If your question is about generating a random number on a button press, we only need to see one button, the function it calls, and a little more code to tie it all together.

Answer (score 1):

```
def button27_pressed():

    Country=['그리스','대한민국','덴마크','독일','라트비아','룩셈부르크',
            '리투아니아','말리','미국','바하마','방글라데시','벨기에',
            '스위스','아이슬란드','아일랜드','영국','오스트리아','이탈리아',
            '인도','일본','중국','체코','태국','튀니지','프랑스','헝가리']

    Flag=random.choice(Country)

    FlagPrint(Flag) # pass in flag as argument

def FlagPrint(Flag): # add Flag parameter
    ...
```